# SQL запрос просто ни чего не выводит PDO

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, pdo

**Файл functions.php**

```
include __DIR__ . "/mysql.php";

function checkPassword($pass, $email){
    $mysql = new Mysql();   
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users where `email` = ':email' AND `password` = ':password'";
    $params = [':email' => $email, ':password' => md5($pass)];
    var_dump($mysql->query($sql, $params));
}
```

**Функция query из mysql.php**

```
public function query($sql, $params=[])
    {
        try {
            $sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $sth->execute($params);
            return $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Ошбика при выполнение запроса: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

**Проверяю функцию в index.php**

```
include(__DIR__. '/core/functions.php');
checkPassword('123123','qwe@mail.ru');
```

И он мне выводит просто:

> array(0) { }

В указанных параметрах все правильно, проверил через phpMyAdmin там находит.

> SELECT * FROM users where `email` = 'qwe@mail.ru' AND `password` = MD5('123123')

Вот скрин:

[image: Скрин]

Попробовал изменить SQL запрос на такой:

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";

И у меня все вывелось, вывел всех пользователей. Получается проблема где то с массивом $params или что-то другое, не могу понять...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:email и :password в sql запросе должны быть без кавычек

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where `email` = :email AND `password` = :password";
```

Comment: Ну у меня из начало их не было... Я их добавил только щас... И тогда когда их не было у меня все равно не работало. А сейчас ты сказал их убрать, я убрал и все заработало, что за магия... Thanks.

Comment: Может файл на сервер не залился или не сохранился. Бывает. но должно быть без кавычек.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть проблема с MD5 ?

Ваш запрос в PHP

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where `email` = ':email' AND `password` = ':password'"

А вот запрос в phpmyadmin:

SELECT * FROM users where email = 'qwe@mail.ru' AND password = **MD5**('123123')

попробуйте md5 убрать из параметров и вызвать внутри запроса:

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where `email` = :email AND `password` = **MD5**(:password)";

Либо проверьте простой запрос с одним параметром для email